# Year-end Commerce receipts

Tags: commerce

I've just stepped in to help work on a half-built Drupal 7 Commerce site for a non-profit who needs to provide year-end receipts to their donors.

Ironically, I can't locate a module which summaries a year's giving. Views is proving problematic.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view, https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows, and https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator

I built a view (Commerce Order) which used the Commerce Order: Uid as a contextual filter and returned line items, using Views Aggregator to tally the item totals and return a yearly total.

I built another view (User), adding the first view as a field; merging rows when necessary, using User: Uid as the merged row's filter.

Things like the address block and thank you paragraph were placed in the User view and rendered above the line items.

Feels kludgy, but seems to work.